# How to query an array on a db firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I don't think I'm very far from the answer, I tried to query an id inside an array on Firestore.

I wanna compare the id of the participants.

Also my DB in Firestore:

[image]

And also my function, for the moment my function return size =0 so they can't catch the query.

```
const deleteAbuse = (type) => {
    const participants = channel?.otherParticipants;
    if (!participants || participants.length != 1) {
      return;
    }
    const myID = currentUser.id;
    const otherUserID = participants[0].id;
    console.log('id user', otherUserID);
    channelDB
      .where('participants.id', '==', otherUserID)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log(querySnapshot.size);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.ref);
          //doc.ref.delete();
        });
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can query filter your "channels" collection to get documents based only on a single field of an object that exists inside the `participants` array. In other words, you cannot create that filtering based only on that ID. To be able to filter the data, you should pass to the `where()` function, the **entire** object, and **not** only some partial data. The object should contain values for all the fields. Only the ID is not enough.

> And also my function, for the moment my function return size =0

That's the expected behavior since in your array there isn't any object that holds only a single field called `id`. All objects hold 7 fields, or even more than that, as I cannot see all fields in your screenshot.

I wrote an article called:

- [How to update an array of objects in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073)

Where you can find in the first part, the simplest way to get a custom object from an array of custom objects.

Alternatively, you can create an array that can hold **only** the IDs of the participants, filter the documents and create another database call to get their corresponding data.

Comment: Can you please repost this article somewhere reasonable like dev.to? Medium is now greedy enough to not have a free tier for anon users anymore.