# Flutter: How can use FieldValue.arrayRemove?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I delete an array of array of objects from Firestore? I want to delete it inside a list.generate

Here is my database structure, I want to delete [{street A, number 25}]

[image]

```
List.generate(
  ...
  IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.trash),
    onPressed: () async {
      try {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(data['uid'])
            .update(
          {
            'adress':
                FieldValue.arrayRemove(
                    ??)
          },
        );
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    },
  ),
)),
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to delete.

Comment: I have just edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, the `adress` field is **not** of type array, it's a Map:

[image]

So there is no way you can call `FieldValue.arrayRemove`. If you want to remove that field, then please use the following lines of code:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(data['uid']).set(
    {'adress': FieldValue.delete()},
    SetOptions(
      merge: true,
    ),
)
```

**Edit:**

After you have updated the screenshot, now the `adress` field is indeed of type array:

[image]

If you want to delete a specific object from the array using `FieldValue.delete()`, you should use [all the data in the object and **not** partial data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462510/how-to-query-an-array-on-a-db-firestore). I have even written an article regarding updating an array of objects in Cloud Firestore:

- [How to update an array of objects in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073)

**Edit2:**

In code it should look like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(data['uid']).update({
    'adress': FieldValue.arrayRemove(elementToDelete),
});
```

Please note that `elementToDelete` object should contain both fields populated. The `number` should hold the value of "25" and `street` should hold the value of "street A". It will not work if you use only one.

However, if you thought that Firestore provides a direct way to delete an array element by index, please note that is **not** possible. In such a case, you'll have to read the document, remove the element from the array, then write the document back to Firestore.

Comment: but what I do If a have more adresses and I want to delete just one?

Comment: There is no way you can add multiple addresses under the `adress` field. Since it's a Map, it doesn't allow duplicate keys. So only one address can be stored. If you want to add multiple addresses then you should change the type of the property from Map to array.

Comment: Ups! I update the photo to show exacthy what I want, sorry for the mistake

Comment: In that case, please check my updated answer.

Comment: I can't follow your tutorial, I'm new with flutter and I I am not able to fully understand it. Can u please wrote a simple solution for me?

Comment: Thanks it works for me, every field must be same, so that can be executed.