# How to query complex firestore document (nested list of objects)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have this document:

```json
{
    "artifact": {
        "id": 1,
        "tags" : [
            "art",
            "art2"
        ],
        "origins": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "tags" : [
                    "o1",
                    "o11"
                ],
                "origins": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "tags" : [
                            "o2",
                            "o3"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "insertionDate": "15022023095425"
}
```

I need to write a query to check if an id matches the id of the deepest origins object of another document.

At first, I thought something like this would work:

```py
common_elements = db.collection("tasks").where("artifact.origins.origins.id", "==", current_item_id)
```

Is it possible to query object properties in a nested list with Firestore?

If this is not possible, how should I remodel my data?
Could I store origins objects in another collection and reference them in this document?

Comment: You don't. It's impossible. You can query collections, not documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to write a query to check if an id matches the id of the deepest origins object of another document.

Using your actual database schema, [you cannot perform such a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144965/how-to-search-for-specific-fields-in-an-array-of-objects-containing-objects-in-a). If you only need to filter documents from the `tasks` collection by the deepest ID, then you should consider creating a non-nested field inside the document called `deepestId`, which in your example should contain the value of `3` and perform the following query:

```
common_elements = db.collection("tasks").where("deepestId", "==", 3)
```

If such a query can return multiple results, then you should add another `where()` call, to filter the documents based on the `deepestId` and the `id` like this:

```
common_elements = db.collection("tasks").where("deepestId", "==", 3).where("id", "==", 1)
```

Another possible solution would be to duplicate the data by creating another collection that should contain only the tasks with the `deepestId == 3`.

Comment: Hey Lucas. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex. I decided to store all origins object in a different collection. I replace the origins objects within origins container with their ids. Doing so I can browse the origins "tree".