# How can I update a nested field in a firestore database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, e-commerce

I am creating a clothing e-commerce application integrated with woocommerce and Firestore.

I currently am trying to build the 'add to wishlist part, here I am struggling with trying to update the items 'favourite' field in the database.

I present my Firestore"
[my Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLRAv.jpg)

I have access to the item on my react native side
I need to be able to iterate through the objects, compare the nested object items ID against the idea of the item I am currently clicking on and change the favorite field to true.
Currently, I have tried to do the following, but to no avail.

```
const like = (item) => {
// db.collection("users").doc(user).collection("wishlist").doc(random).set({
//   id:item.id,
//   name:item.name,
// })

db.collection("users")
  .doc(user)
  .collection("products")
  .doc("0")
  .get()
  .then((data) => {
    const info = data.data();
  });
```

};

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform an update to an object that exists in an array-type field, you need to find that particular object first. Unfortunately, there is no way you can query a Firestore collection based on a value that exists in an object that is contained in an array. This kind of filtering cannot be achieved [using partial data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462510/how-to-query-an-array-on-a-db-firestore). To solve this, you have to read the array, find the desired elements that need to be updated, perform the update and then write the document back to Firestore.

I have also written an article called:

- [How to update an array of objects in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073)

Comment: Hey Sheran. Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

so at the end I came up with a solution which I thought I would share here:

```
const like = (item) => {
    const newData = { ...Data };
    if (newData !== null) {
      let index = newData.Products.findIndex((e) => {
        return e.id === item.id;
      });
      console.log(index);
      newData.Products[index].favourite = true;
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(userID)
        .collection("products")
        .doc("0")
        .set(newData)
        .then((data) => setData(data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    } else {
      alert("An error has occured");
    }
  };
```

so this takes the data, saves it,  adds the particular change and sets it again