# Firestore Keywords database design

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a product model and a keyword model which looks like this:

```
class Product{
    String id;
    String name;
    List<KeyWord> keywords;
...

}
class KeyWord{
    String id;
    String title;
}
```

How to store them in Firestore to enable searching products by their keywords,
And show a drop-down list of some pre-saved keywords like what happens in the stack overflow keywords system.

Comment: Do you need the Firestore schema for that? How many keywords can be in a single list?

Comment: @AlexMamo
yeah I need firestore schema for that,
each product can have up to 20 keywords

Comment: To a question raised by @AlexMamo answer; Why does the `KeyWord` have an `id`? Are they in some way reusable with other products? If not, then remove that and you can just store the items in an array `0: some keyword` and `1: another keyword` and you are all set with that answer. If not, it could change the entire approach (an array of maps for example)

Comment: @Jay For sure Jay, it makes totally sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that a list might have up to 20 keywords, then the database schema might look like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- products (collection)
        |
        --- $productId (document)
               |
               --- keywords (array)
                     |
                     --- 0
                         |
                         --- id: "keywordId"
                         |
                         --- title: "keywordTitle"
```

I'm not sure why would use an id of the keyword, but if you don't actually need it, then I recommend you store strings within the array and not `KeyWord` objects.

When you store string, you can easily query the products collection based on a specific keyword using:

```
final productsRef = db.collection("products");
final queryByKeyword = productsRef.where("keywords", arrayContains: "keyword");
```

Otherwise, you'll have to [query using the entire object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69462510/how-to-query-an-array-on-a-db-firestore).